# Azure VM, not being able to redirect domain

Tags: azure, redirect, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I have a domain which is www.avvakampus.com.tr and what I want to is to redirct this domain to my Azure VM. However so far no luck.

**What I have done so far?**

The domain provider has only allows nameservers in it's portal. So i give lisanegitim.cloudapp.net as my nameserver, which is the url of my azure cloud service.

as you can see it is already redirected to lisanegitim.cloduapp

http://www.dnsinspect.com/avvakampus.com.tr/1462713328

And I also had added the DNS records to my DNS manager.

[image]

However when I try to load or psping it is unable to be reached. I am very confused and lost. Please any suggestion might be helpful.

BTW, I was able to redirect another domain which is www.edumap.net by simply adding A records on it's panel. However, their domain providers are not the same and edumap's domain portal gives you the ability of adding IP addresses, A records and etc but www.avvakampus.com.tr do not.

Regards.

Comment: This question is [off topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), but might be suitable for the [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). Before re-posting there, please first [search](http://serverfault.com/search) to see if it has been asked before. Be sure to read [How to ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) first!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some misunderstandings here on how you should set up your DNS.

Firstly, the name server you specify in the NS/SOA record should be the name of your name server that is hosting your DNS zone.  It has nothing to do with your Azure VM deployment.

If your DNS zone is avvakampus.com.tr, you should then create a CNAME record called 'www' (so that together, the FQDN is www.avvakampus.com.tr).  The target of the CNAME record should be lisanegitim.cloudapp.net.